# Animating a TextView appearing on activity creation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to show an animation of a TextView appearing when an activity is created. What I want is to show the activity without the TextView and then the TextView appearing (ideally, flying from outside) in its final position without user interaction.

I've tried to use the transition framework from API level 19 by having the TextView with visibility gone in the XML layout and setting it to visible in onCreate() with this code:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout, new ChangeBounds());
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This doesn't work. However, if I don't do this in onCreate() but as a response to a button click, it works. I think that the problem is that the layout is not created yet, so when I set the visibility to visible in the onCreate(), the layout is created with the final state and there aren't two scenes for the TransitionManager to work.

I've tried putting the code in onPause() but the result was the same. Any ideas how this should be done?

Comment: Should you do this using handler and a runnable with some delay ?

Comment: I tried that and it worked, though I find it cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `onWindowFocusChanged()` like this 
`@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        // start your animation here 
    }

}`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in onResume() after the layout has been created. Initially the visibility would be Invisible and then the view will animate.

Comment: It doesn't work: the view shows up immediately without animation.

Comment: I can't write it here in a comment, but I just copied the code in the question inside onResume after the call to super.onResume().

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout, new ChangeBounds());
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
  });
```

because your view should be able to animate only after it's creation

Comment: It doesn't work: the view shows up immediately without animation.

Comment: It's because the view is hidden at time of animation and after that it's showing @user936580